# Running Deduction CTE in SQL Server using declared variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

Can someone please explain to me why I am dumb? I am trying to use this result set to do a running deduction from the variable I declared below. Granted I am newer at CTE's but I figured this would have been INF easier.

[image]

```
DECLARE @monies AS money = 35600.00;

WITH RFRoll AS
(
    SELECT 
        col
        , value
        , Amt = @monies 
    FROM #rfTmp 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        col
        , value
        , CASE 
            WHEN @monies>value then @monies-value
            WHEN value<@monies then @monies-value 
            WHEN value>@monies then @monies-@monies
            END Amt
    FROM #rfTmp 
    WHERE 
        CASE 
            WHEN @monies>value then @monies-value
            WHEN value<@monies then @monies-value 
            WHEN value>@monies then @monies-@monies
            END >0
)
SELECT * 
FROM RFRoll
```

This is the result get I get. It looks as if its just displaying the the current line calculation instead of the running deduction I'm trying to get at.

Ive tried various different ways and I keep running into a brick wall. I keep reverting to this current state which obviously isn't correct b/c I'm not actually using a running total variable.

So I guess my question is how do i do this using a variable? Am I actually able to reset the value recursively? I don't think so? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

The desired out out would be this (not counting the extra fourth column)

[image]

Sorry for adding the 4th column it occurred to me that maybe I haven't truly understood the issue at hand and maybe I ought to rethink my approach. Basically I want cascading deduction up until a value is equal to 0. I have to do all the comparisons b/c a value can never be negative and I cant go over the value of the variable.

I am going to try and rework this in the meantime.

Comment: You should explain what you want.  Non-working code doesn't always help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added what I am hoping to achieve, Thanks for asking me to do hat as it illustarted to me that maybe I dont understand the need versus how to get there. Im going to try a different approach,

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2008, you can use `apply` or a correlated subquery.  The basic structure is:

```
select r.*, r2.running_value
from #rftmp r outer apply
     (select sum(r2.value) as running_value
      from #rftmp r2
      where r2.col <= r.col
     ) t2;
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want to accomplish.

Of course, in SQL Server 2012, the function is built in using a window function with `order by`.

Comment: I think that the comparison operator in the `WHERE`clause should be *less than* (not equal), because in the initial row he wanted to see the value of the variable, and I think that instead of the `r2.running_value` it should be `@monies - r2.running_value` in the SELECT list. Also, the query should stop when all money is gone. But I like it.

Comment: I do like the outer apply approach. I will try and see if I can use it instead of the CTE. The whole point of the task I was doing was to get better practice cte's but adding any useful apporach to my routine will always be valuable;

Comment: @DougCoats . . . Using variables is not a typical approach in SQL Server.

Comment: You never pass values in to or form a proc?

Comment: @DougCoats . . . Of course I do.  I misread your code.  I thought `@money` was being set.

Comment: it is in my example - remember i am was doing practice exercises. I just set it instead of going through the hoops of writing proc/passing value/out putting

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, if anyone cares

```
declare @monies  as money = 35600.00;
WITH RFRoll as
    (
    SELECT 
        #rfTmp.*
        , CASE 
            WHEN @monies>=value then value
            WHEN value<@monies then value 
            WHEN value>@monies then @monies
            END AS Amt
        , CASE 
            WHEN @monies>=value then value
            WHEN value<@monies then value 
            WHEN value>@monies then @monies
            END AS ValueUsed        
    FROM #rfTmp WHERE [No] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        v.*
        , RFRoll.Amt + CASE 
            WHEN v.value>@monies-RFRoll.Amt then @monies-RFRoll.Amt
            WHEN v.value<@monies-RFRoll.Amt then v.value 
            WHEN @monies-RFRoll.Amt>v.value then v.value
            END
        , CASE 
            WHEN v.value>@monies-RFRoll.Amt then @monies-RFRoll.Amt
            WHEN v.value<@monies-RFRoll.Amt then v.value 
            WHEN @monies-RFRoll.Amt>v.value then v.value
            END
    FROM #rfTmp v INNER JOIN RFRoll ON v.[No] = RFRoll.[No] + 1
    WHERE RFRoll.Amt<@monies 
    )
    SELECT * FROM RFRoll
```

Comment: Where does the magic `No` come from? 2 of 3 `WHEN` cases are equivalent and I think that the 3rd one can be removed since in these cases the `WHERE` clause ends the recursion.

Comment: Ah I knew I forgot to include the temp table. Mostly, my question was related to why my math skills suck, but also related to the temp table I used. The third case will need ot be reworked then, as there is a third scenario. Thanks for pointing that out. Either way, I was able to get there on my own - sometimes just the simple process of asking questions helps you rethink it